# Cannot find 'LoginInteractor' in scope

Tags: swift, facebook, authentication, sdk

Hello I'm trying to make a connection via facebook in the project I already use a LoginInteractor but when I want to use the class in another file it does not find it.

```swift
import Foundation
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKLoginKit

class LoginViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var email = ""
    @Published var error = false
    @Published var validationButton = false
    @Published var showIng = false
    @Published var signup = false
    @Published var signIn = false
    
    private let loginInteractor = LoginInteractor()
    
    init() {
        ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(
            UIApplication.shared,
            didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: nil
        )
    }
    func loginWithFacebook(fromViewController sourceViewController: UIViewController) {
        // Appeler la méthode de LoginInteractor pour gérer la connexion Facebook
        loginInteractor.loginUser(fromViewController: sourceViewController) { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let userData):
                // Utilisez les données de l'utilisateur (nom, email) comme nécessaire
                let name = userData["name"] as? String
                let email = userData["email"] as? String
                
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Erreur de connexion Facebook : \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: since publishing my post I have not found a solution